# Precondition for TreeMap

Tags: java, collections, coding-style

Like for a object to be inserted into a HashMap the object should implement the equals() and the hashcode() method(not necessarily). 
Are there any special conditions for an object to be inserted in a TreeMap ?

Answer (score 3):

Unless a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which mutually compares the keys is provided in the `TreeMap`'s constructor, the keys must implement [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

See the javadocs on `TreeMap` constructors for more information: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

**EDIT:** As [@MeBigFatGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100565/mebigfatguy) points out it is highly recommended for keys to override [equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) as well, in such a way that the implementation is consistent with the comparison. From the `TreeMap` javadoc:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted map (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) *must be consistent with equals* if this sorted map is to correctly implement the `Map` interface. (See `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a precise definition of *consistent with equals*.) This is so because the `Map` interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a map performs all key comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal. The behavior of a sorted map *is* well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Map` interface.

Comment: @Sahil - Thanks for spotting that mistake!

Comment: i think it would be wise to implement equals as well.

Answer (score 0):

The type/class should (again, not necessarily) implement the [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface (and override the `compareTo` method), so as to decide the ordering within the TreeMap.